# Как можно раскрутить социальную сеть?

Tags: реклама, раскрутка

Можете подсказать, как можно раскрутить социальную сеть, реклама не помогает, я пробовал на яндекс, вк и гугл, со всех кликов 60, никто зарегистрировался.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос не по теме сайта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замутить хороший контент, красиво оформить, для начала пригласить туда друзей, потом попросить у них обратную связь